# Batch Normalization Vs. Instance Normalization Vs. Adaptive Instance Normalization

Tags: generative-adversarial-network, batch-normalization, style-transfer

What is the difference between Batch Normalization, Instance Normalization, Adaptive Instance Normalization layers in a CNN?Which one should be used in generative models for image stylization?

I am actually trying to train a GAN model for style transfer and am confused as to what type of normalization layer should be used. Or should I not use it at all?